# SQL relation between 3 tables

Tags: sql

I need some help with an SQL statement...

I have tree tables

- Problems
- Solutions
- Employees

The `Problem` table contains an `ID`, a `description` of the problem and the `ID` of the person who reported it.

The `Solution` table contains an `ID`, `description` of the solution and the `ID` of the person who solved the problem.

The `Employee` table contains an `ID`, the first and last names of all the employees of a company.

The ID of the solver and the reporter are related to the ID of the employee

I want to write a query that gives me the description of the problem and the solution and the first and last name of the employee who reported and solved it.

This is the query I have to select everything I need except the name of the solver..

```
SELECT        
   P.ProblemID, 
   P.Description AS ProblemDescription, 
   P.SolutionID,  
   P.ReporterID, 
   E.FirstName,
   E.LastName, 
   S.SolverID, 
   S.Description AS SolutionDescription
FROM            
   (tblProblem P 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   tblEmployee E ON P.ReporterID = E.EmployeeID) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   tblSolution S ON P.SolutionID = S.SolutionID;
```

I really hope someone can help me with this..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join on the employee marked as the solver as well. Following your style and not knowing your exact column names:

```
SELECT        
          P.ProblemID, 
          P.Description AS ProblemDescription, 
          P.SolutionID,

          P.ReporterID, 
          E.FirstName,
          E.LastName, 
          S.SolverID, 
          S.Description AS SolutionDescription,
          E2.FirstName as SolverFirstName,
          E2.LastName as SolverLastName
```

FROM

```
         (tblProblem P LEFT OUTER JOIN 
          tblEmployee E ON P.ReporterID = E.EmployeeID) 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN 
          tblSolution S ON P.SolutionID = S.SolutionID
          LEFT OUTER JOIN
          tblEmployee E2 ON S.SolverID = E2.EmployeeID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just join the employee table again, once for the solver and once for the reporter:

```
SELECT        P.ProblemID, 
              P.Description AS ProblemDescription, 
              P.SolutionID,

              P.ReporterID, 
              RE.FirstName as ReporterFirstname,
              RE.LastName as ReporterLastname, 
              S.SolverID, 
              S.Description AS SolutionDescription,
              SE.FirstName as SolverFirstname,
              SE.LastName as SolverLastname
FROM

             ((tblProblem P LEFT OUTER JOIN 
              tblEmployee RE ON P.ReporterID = RE.EmployeeID) LEFT OUTER JOIN 
              tblSolution S ON P.SolutionID = S.SolutionID) LEFT OUTER JOIN 
              tblEmployee SE ON P.ReporterID = SE.EmployeeID
```

PS: I saw you using parentheses. Are you using Access? If so, I hope I got them right.

Comment: I am using Access indeed, and you got them right :) Thanks a lot for helping me out!