# SQL relation between 3 table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing a class project that consist of three tables: Member, Event and Attendance.

- The Member table contains: MID as primary key, Name, Address, etc... and has a 1 or many to 0 or many relation with Attendance
- The Event table contains: EventNo as primary key, EventName, etc...and has a 1 or many to 0 or many relation with Attendance
- The Attendance contains: MID and EventNo

I can create the table but I don't understand their relation. Could anyone briefly explain their relationship and help me write the code??? Thanks in advance

Comment: The best way to understand the relation is to draw it and if that doesn't help - try it at home! You should first show your effort to understand the thing on your own and this basically tells you to test it out first :)

Comment: Just to confirm are you actually using Microsoft SQL Server? The syntax between databases vary. The relationships should be established by defining foreign key constraints. As for the cardinality that isn't really relevant to the DDL of the table, would come into play if you were drawing out a diagram though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL relation between 3 tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853781/sql-relation-between-3-tables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Member
    ([MID] int primary key, [Name] varchar(5), [Address] varchar(8))
;

INSERT INTO Member
    ([MID], [Name], [Address])
VALUES
    (1, 'Name1', 'Address1')
;



CREATE TABLE Event
    ([EventNo] int primary key, [EventName] varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO Event
    ([EventNo], [EventName])
VALUES
    (1, 'Event1')
;

    CREATE TABLE Attendance
        ([EventNo] int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Event(EventNo), [MID] int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Member(MID))
    ;

INSERT INTO Attendance
    ([EventNo], [MID])
VALUES
    (1, 1)
;
```

**Select query will be like this**

```
select * from Event join Attendance on Event.EventNo=Attendance.EventNo
join Member on Member.MID=Attendance.MID
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ab015/3)

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
create table member (
  MID INT primary key ...,
  Name VARCHAR(30),
  ...
);

create table event (
  EventNo INT primary key ...,
  EventName VARCHAR(30),
  ...
);

create table attenance (
  EventNo INT,
  MID INT,
  //here add constraint for MID and EventNo - they are  foreign key from other tables.
  UNIQUE(EventNo, MID)
);
```

and it appears, that you have relation: `many-to-many` between event and member. `One member` can be in `many events`. `One event` can has `many members`.

Spelling correction

Comment: So do I have to create the relation between the Event and Member table??? If so how to do it???

Comment: look in the second answer.